# Transactions prioritization in block

Tags: nearprotocol

In Ethereum transaction has a `gas_price` and miners include transactions with the higher `gas_price` first. How block producers prioritize transactions in Near?

Comment: NEAR is sharded: transactions that affect only a certain shard will be prioritized over others for nodes on that shard (https://near.org/papers/nightshade/#nightshade 3.3). However, it's probably rare to only need accounts from a certain shard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Near gas price is global for the entire system. Chunk producers might have incentives to include transactions with higher fee since they also get paid with certain percentage of the fee back, but also fees are supposed to reflect actual cost of the corresponding operation. So at the end if our fee model is perfect chunk producers should be indifferent to what transactions they include as long as their cumulative fee adds up to the max gas in the block.

Comment: Thanks! So, how the global `gas_price` is going to be determined?